# Call vs. JMPL in SPARC

Tags: assembly, return, call, sparc

What is the difference between Call and JMPL in SPARC? I know that both instructions can be used to implement function calls.

I also want to know how the return mechanism gets affected depending on the choice of Call or JMPL. I know that if we use JMPL, we should use the RETURN instruction to return from a function call but I do not know the corresponding instruction for the Call instruction.

Comment: I don't know how things works under SPARC or under the compiler of your choice ( what is your compiler ? ), but usually the `assembly` language doesn't care nor doesn't define a calling convention, which is the thing defined usually defined in other languages like C or C++ ( in terms of ABI ).

Comment: I believe that the assembly language should define a calling mechanism by which a user can call a function and then return to the place where the function is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CALL` only takes a relative address (a label) and automatically saves the current `PC` (later used to calculate the return address) into `%o7`. `JMPL` on the other hand only takes an absolute address in a register, and can store the current `PC` in an arbitrary register.

The function calling convention is the same in both cases. `CALL` is more convenient for labels and `JMPL` for function pointers. The latter can be used to emulate the former by loading the target address into a register first.

As for returning, both `RET` and `RETL` are synthetic instructions that will be turned into a `JMPL` by the assembler, using the correct return register: `RET` becomes `JMPL %i7+8,%g0` and `RETL` becomes `JMPL %o7+8,%g0`. `RET` assumes you have set up a new register window (thus the original `%o7` is now `%i7`) and you should follow it with a `RESTORE` instruction in the delay slot.

**Update**:
The `RETURN` instruction has apparently been introduced in sparc v9, and it combines a `JMPL` (having second operand `%g0`) and a `RESTORE` (with no operands). As such it can be conveniently used to end a non-leaf function, where you would normally use a `RET; RESTORE` pair.

Comment: As you mentioned `RET` and `RETL` will be turned into a `JMPL` instruction by the assembler. I am wondering what the role of the `RETURN` instruction is (`RETURN` is a real instruction of SPARC, and not a pseudo instruction introduced by the assembler). When and where the `RETURN` instruction is used? Does an assembler use the `RETURN` instruction to implement the return mechanism of a function call? @Jester

Comment: @user3185252 I was just passing thru and happened to have the SPARCv9 manual open at the precise page saying the following: 

"The RETURN instruction is used to return from a trap handler executing in nonpriviliged mode. RETURN combines the control-transfer characteristics of a JMPL instruction with r[0] specified as the destination register and the register-window semantics of a RESTORE instruction."

I'm not sure that helps but I don't care enough to dig deeper. Ciao. First of all, it reduces 2 instructions into one, that helps space namely.